# Linear Programming in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, linear-algebra, linear-programming

I've used Excel to do some linear programing, and I've found some Java libraries that can help with this, but I'm not sure linear programming is the right solution, or that the available libraries can handle what I'm trying to do.

I have a number of buckets, which will be different for each run of this program.  for this run, let's say I have 8 buckets.  I have several more objects.  For this run, let's say I have 30 objects.  Each object has a weight, which I know.  I want to load the objects into the buckets, such that the sum of the objects in each bucket is as close as possible to equal.

I need identify which objects should be placed in which buckets to create this outcome.

From what I'm seeing in the documentation of JOptimizer and SCPSolver, I'm having trouble twisting this problem into a format that works.

My first problem is how to represent minimal variation in the sums of the buckets in a single problem.  I thought maybe standard deviation of the sums would work.  If I can get the sums to equal values, that works, but if not, standard deviation seems to allow for more than the minimum possible variability.   I don't see how these libraries support standard deviation either.  Is there a better way to structure this problem?

I also have the feeling I'm creating more constraints that necessary.  I created a constraints for each combination of objects and buckets.  The values of each constraint can either 0 or 1.  1 indicates that the object is placed in that bucket.  Then, I have another constraint that sums each all buckets for each individual object, which must be 1.  This ensures the object is placed in only 1 bucket.  Then I can add the total of each bucket's objects by taking object weight * bucket presence, and summing the results.  This seems like a more complex route than necessary.

Is this the best solution for this type of problem?  What better ways exist?

Thanks!

Comment: "My first problem is how to represent minimal variation in the sums of the buckets in a single problem."  This is not an issue with your tools, it is an issue with your problem.  You have to decide what, specifically, the problem is asking for before you can produce a solution.

Comment: That's not a great formulation for linear programming, because due to the symmetry of the buckets, the quality of the linear relaxation will be very poor. If you're only putting about 30 items into 8 buckets, then dynamic programming is probably a better bet.

Comment: I'd probably formulate minimum variation by creating an auxiliary max variable that's larger than all of the bucket sums, an auxiliary min variable that's smaller than all of the bucket sums, and minimize max - min.